# How to return an empty viewcomponent MVC 6?

Tags: c#, .net, web, asp.net-core-mvc

I have searched but I did not find any way to return an empty IViewComponentResult. The only way I managed to do it is by returning an empty View. Is there a better way? 
This is my code:

```
public class ClientNavigationViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return User.IsInRole(UserRoles.CLIENT)
            ? View("_ClientMenu")
            : (IViewComponentResult)new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in  but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.EmptyResult' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.IViewComponentResult'.

I have tried to return null but that won't work too. Any ideas?
EDIT Made it work like this:

```
public class ClientNavigationViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        if (User.IsInRole(UserRoles.CLIENT))
            return View("_ClientMenu");
        return new EmptyViewComponent();
    }
}

public class EmptyViewComponent : IViewComponentResult
{
    public void Execute(ViewComponentContext context)
    {
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property can inherit from an interface not cast to it.

Try create an object which is inherits from IViewComponentResult.

```
public class xyz: IViewComponentResult
{
  // todo
}
```

then return this object. It should work.

Answer (score 39):

You can do the following :

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
  if (User.IsInRole(UserRoles.CLIENT))
     return View("_ClientMenu");

  return Content(string.Empty);
}
```